# get infinity input PIL (python)

Tags: python, input, python-imaging-library

I'm writing a program that converts image to png and converts size to 512,
I want to get more input.

```
from PIL import Image
import string
import random

put = input("enter your image path:")
im = Image.open(put)
size = (512,512)

if im.size > size:
        im.thumbnail(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)    
else:
       print ("it's ready")

ranam = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(12)))
name = "d:/arjang/images/" + ranam

im.save(name + ".png")
```

Please help.

Comment: `i want to get more input` What do you mean by this?

Comment: Question is unclear. My guess: you want to have your script to ask again for another image path after it has finished resizing one ? In a loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop, asking for another image path to resize, until you enter an empty string:

```
from PIL import Image
import string
import random

while True:

    put = input("enter your image path:")
    if not put.strip(): break
    im = Image.open(put)
    size = (512,512)
    if im.size > size:

        im.thumbnail(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)

    else:
        print ("it's ready")

    ranam = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(12)))
    name = "d:/arjang/images/" + ranam

    im.save(name + ".png")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been mislead by the "input() function. Its does not do what you would hope a function called input will do. input executes what you type as code.

This is so misleading that python3 changed "input()" to do the obvious and removed raw_input().

To read a line from the standard input you can use this in python2:

```
put = raw_input("enter your image path:")
```

or you could do this:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("enter your image path:")
sys.atdout.flush()
put = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
```